# Удаление строки из записи

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Вот что есть, но не знаю в чем ошибка...

```
void del(item * q) 
{ 
    if (q == first) {
        first = first->next;
    } else { 
        item * d = first; 
        while (d->next!= q) {
            d = d->next;
        } 
        d->next = q->next; 
        if (q == last) last = d; 
        delete q; 
    } 
}

void delMenu() 
{ 
    system("cls"); 
    int ID; 
    cout<<"Введите номер записи: "; 
    cin>>ID; 
    item * r = last;

    if(r!= NULL) { 
        while(r->inf.id == ID && r->next!= NULL) { 
            r=r->next; 
        } 
        if(r->inf.id == ID) del(r);
        else cout<<"Запись не найдена в базе\n"; 
    } else { 
        cout<<"Записей нет"; 
    } 
    _getch(); 
}
```

Comment: @Валентин, в следующий раз, пожалуйста, форматируйте код сами.

Comment: @Валентин, а что не работает?

Comment: да просто вылазит ошибка самого компилятора что мол не тот адрес и тд и тп

Comment: Какие конкретно ошибки компилятора? И дайте больше кода. Из приведенного мало что можно выяснить

Answer (score 1):

[@Валентин](/users/7850/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD), если валится во время выполнения, то это **не называют** "ошибка самого компилятора" (говорят *ошибка времени исполнения* или просто *runtime error*)

Судя по словам "адрес не тот" могу предположить, что это *runtime error* и ошибка где-то в построении списка (возможно last != NULL , но он указывает на память, **не выделявшуюся по new**).

Используйте отладчик. Очень помогает.

Вообще у Вас тут несколько ошибочек.

1). в **delMenu** в **while** Вы начинаете с **last** (???), а из кода **del()** следует что список начинается с **first**.

2). условие в **while(r->inf.id == ID && r->next!= NULL)** попросту неправильное (без учета ошибки 1). Должно быть **inf.id != ID**

3). в **del()** оператор **delete q;** надо вытащить из **else** в конец (после всего **if**).
Вообще **del()** сделана неаккуратно (в предположении, что **q** есть в списке).

И наконец, такая идея работы со списком неэффективная. Вы ***дважды*** пробегаете (в среднем половину) по списку.  Если удаляете (вставляете после, перед) по адресу элемента списка, то делайте двусвязный список. Тогда искать при выполнении такой операции ничего не надо.

Если почему-то обязательно нужен односвязный, то делайте удаление не по адресу, а по **ID**, т.е. совмещаете поиск и удаление. Получится что-то вроде

```
if (!first)
   cout << "Нет записей";
else {
   cout<<"Введите номер записи: "; 
   cin>>ID; 
   if (!findDel(ID))
      cout<<"Запись не найдена в базе\n";
}
```

Comment: благодарю за такой пояснительный ответ, буду разбираться